# Can mercenaries be self-sufficient for rubies?

Tags: clicker-heroes

In Clicker Heroes, the newly added mercenaries have a chance to die on each mission they're assigned. Resurrecting them costs rubies, the amount of which is based on the level of the mercenary.

I have a set of 5 level 1-5 mercenaries, and even though I try to pick missions that reward rubies as often as possible, it feels like a huge ruby sink.

Do mercenaries ever get self-sufficient for rubies as you level them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **No**.

They can be *temporarily* self-sufficient, but once they reach a high enough level, the ruby cost to revive them grows [**much**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfOi9.png) faster than their expected income per life.

See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/comments/42gzx4/partially_updated_merc_revive_analysis/) for some guidelines on when it is or isn't worth reviving mercs.

Comment: know the feels man. My fabled merc (+24 Demigod) died today and not even my transcended merc for 2000% rubies could save him :(